# How do I set a base domain for gitlab's auto devops?

Tags: gitlab

Docs seem to point to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/index.html#base-domain

However it doesn't seem to specify how to set the base domain strangely enough.

Can't seem to find info no this via a web search, I've also looked at https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/quick_start_guide.html#install-ingress

> Go back to the cluster page on GitLab, and go to the Details tab. Add
> your Base domain. For this guide, use the domain .nip.io.
> Click Save changes.

I think this option only showed up AFTER I installed the ingress.